# Tag Delete: Memory

Tags: discussion, tagging

As from title, I propose to delete the [memory](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory) tag.
It is used only by one question and it could live without it (actual question is about disposing practices, so [disposing](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disposing) should be enough).

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags/memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to delete tags. But, tags that are not used by any questions will be deleted in about 24 hours.

So I propose that you edit the question, to replace the tag with [disposing](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disposing). If the edit is accepted the tag should self-destruct :)

Comment: my bad then - I saw some "Burinate tag" requests on the main meta site so I assumed it was a mod task. Will remove it thanks.

Comment: Actually I did not know how it worked until you asked ;)